# Getting user environment variables using PHP

Tags: php, centos, environment-variables, redhat

On centos and Redhat I created a file /etc/profile.d/marketing_vars.sh and added following lines to it

```
#Vars  for PowerMail
export CmsRoot="/var/www/html/cms/"
export PMRoot_Dev="/var/www/html/powermail/"
export PMRoot_QA="/var/www/html/powermail/"
export PMRoot_Pro="/var/www/html/powermail/"
```

On command line i hit "source marketing_vars.sh"
and "chmod +x /etc/profile.d/marketing_vars.sh"

I then created a test.php file and added these lines to it

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
echo "PMRoot_Dev = " . getenv("PMRoot_Dev");
echo "<br>";
echo "PMRoot_QA = " . getenv("PMRoot_QA");
echo "<br>";
echo "PMRoot_Pro = " . getenv("PMRoot_Pro");
echo "<br>";
```

When I browse a test.php  I get no value for any of the variable. Can anyone help ?

Comment: does `echo $CmsRoot` (or `echo` others) show any output?

Comment: @Baldrs No, it show nothing

Comment: I think you use a browser, so you have a webserver. Are you sure the webserver (Apache?) is running as a user with those variables set? My guess: you only set those variables for your user account, while apache is running under the www-data user.

Comment: @user1635914 forgot to mention, you must `echo $CmsRoot` in shell, not in php. If it shows nothing in the shell, check your `profile.d` and `/etc/profile` again. Also, if it's intended to be used in server(apache), you should restart it from the shell that already sourced script from `profile.d`

Comment: @Jeroen I think you are recommending to put them also in .htaccess, I just want to read var that I set in marketing_vars.sh file.How can I do that ?

Comment: @Baldrs echo $CmsRoot is returning nothing but getenv("PMRoot_Dev") is returning proper values on shell. I restarted using /sbin/service httpd restart but still its not coming on browser.

Comment: @user1635914 try adding `. /etc/profile.d/marketing_vars.sh ` to ~/.bashrc of user you run httpd. profile.d seems to be ignored, just sourcing in resolves missing vars

Comment: @Baldrs I located following instances of bashrc 

/etc/bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/root/.bashrc

I added my vars last two files and sourced files , but they are not coming on browsers

Comment: @user1635914 but why do it using env? You can use config.php or something like that

Comment: @Baldrs I know, unfortunately this is requirement from client, cant help it out. but its strange that its working on CLI and not on browser

Answer (score 0):

Apache on Centos doesn't include the env variables like you expect. One solution is to include by hand the file inside /etc/sysconfig/httpd.

- append /etc/profile.d/marketing_vars.sh to the end of /etc/sysconfig/httpd
- restart apache

The best solution to be consistent in apache, CLI and crons is to use a configuration file and include/parse it to get the variable.