# Environment variable in PHP-docker container

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, openshift, openshift-origin

I want to show an env var in my docker container.
The PHP script looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Show Use of environment variables</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
  print "env is: ".$_ENV["USER"]."\n";
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

I use OpenShift to start the container. The PHP - container shows:

```
env is:
```

Now I change the dc config of my container:

```
oc env dc/envar USER=Pieter
deploymentconfig "envar" updated
```

When I access the container. The env var of USER is Pieter

```
docker exec -it 44a0f446ae36 bash
bash-4.2$ echo $USER
Pieter
```

But my script remains showing: "`env is:`" It does not fill in the variable.

Comment: What does the log shows?

Comment: did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

Change

```
print "env is: ".$_ENV["USER"]."\n";
```

to

```
print "env is: ".getenv("USER")."\n";
```

.

`test.php`

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Show Use of environment variables</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
  print "env via \$_ENV is: ".$_ENV["USER"]."\n";
  print "env via getenv is: ".getenv("USER")."\n";
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
# export USER=Sascha
# echo $USER
Sascha
```

`php test.php`

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Show Use of environment variables</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /test.php on line 7
    PHP Notice:  Undefined index: USER in /test.php on line 7
    env via $_ENV is: 
    env via getenv is: Sascha
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Worked for me. That was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to solve this issue:

1. Use this command that writes the environment variables to a file called .env in your project folder.

   ```
   CMD ["env >> /path/to/project/.env"]
   ```
2. Install dotenv package that loads the env variables from a file to $_ENV

   ```
   composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
   ```
3. Load the package and use it as

   ```
   require 'vendor/autoload.php'
   $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
   $dotenv->load();
   getenv('VAR_NAME');
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['VAR_NAME']` instead of `getenv()` or `$_ENV` when accessing environmental variables, to be thread-safe and follow good practice.

Comment: The comment from @Deele should be the right answer, depending on how those variables are set can appear either on `getenv` or `$_ENV` and you can get ending will `NULL` or `FALSE` since the variable may not be set. But using `$_SERVER` will work always

Answer (score -2):

You just need to use different quotes, it is working to me with this

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Show Use of environment variables</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
  print "env is: ".$_ENV['USER'];
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain that further - which "different quotes" do you mean? `$_ENV["USER"]` and `$_ENV['USER']` should perform the exact same result. If not, please open a bug report

Comment: He used print "env is: ".$_ENV["USER"]."\n". Index should be in single quotes not in double quotes. I tested it on my computer and it works.

Comment: What makes you think that there is **any** difference between using single or double quotes? Are you sure that your code does not work when using double quotes? Then please file a bug report